# Is i2p-zero integration accessible from monerod cli in 0.15?

Tags: monerod, i2p, i2p-zero

I've heard conflicting answers on this, and would appreciate a definitive response.

One of the reasons i2p-zero was developed was to provide a version of i2p that could be integrated directly into Monero, so a separate install wouldn't be needed.

According to Justin Ehrenhofer on twitter, the i2p-zero integration didn't make it into the GUI, but did make it into the CLI.

However, browsing through the CLI documentation for all the different flags, I see support for i2p that has been separately installed, but I see nothing that would indicate that i2p-zero was successfully built into the executables and is accessible from CLI.

Is i2p-zero now built into Monero? If so, what are the flags to access it? Can you point me to the documentation for those flags, or a tutorial? Note that I am already aware of [ANONYMITY_NETWORKS](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.md), but as far as I can tell this only applies to a separately installed and configured i2p. I'm ideally looking for a flag that you can set to use the built-in i2p-zero to run the node.

Answer (score 2):

The i2p (and tor) integration is purposely implementation agnostic - i.e. it is designed to work with *any* i2p/tor router implementation. There has not yet been any agreement I'm aware of for *packaging* a *specific* router implementation with the core CLI tools.

The GUI however has slightly different nuances / needs when it comes to i2p/tor integration in that typical GUI users just need / want single-click style integration / activation. Hence the first work planned for GUI (if I recall correctly) is to offer the option of downloading and auto-configuration of i2p-zero from within the GUI, not actually packaging i2p-zero alongside the GUI binaries.

The first step was getting the daemon able to use any i2p/tor router, and this was released in v0.14. After this work was completed, then work could begin on the GUI (as outlined above). This was tentatively aimed for the v0.15 release, but unfortunately other priorities got in the way.

So to answer your specific questions:

> Is i2p-zero integration accessible from the monerod cli in 0.15?

Yes, the *integration* options have been in place since v0.14.

> Is i2p-zero now built into Monero?

No, i2p-zero is not "built into" Monero. See detailed answer above.

> If so, what are the flags to access it? Can you point me to the documentation for those flags, or a tutorial?

The flags are detailed in the document you linked to: [ANONYMITY_NETWORKS](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/ANONYMITY_NETWORKS.md).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed information. I've asked some follow-up questions about the flags described in the document: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11797/questions-about-anonymity-networks-md

Comment: Can you give me a contact information? I'm studying monero offline signature